# Which Airline don't use the Flight Number 191 anymore because of bad luck?

Tags: accidents

This question came up while reading an article about [mysterious plane incidents](http://listverse.com/2013/07/26/10-mysterious-plane-crashes/). It told that some airlines do not use the [flight number 191](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_191) because of bad luck.

> In fact, there have been so many catastrophes that, much like hotel
>   owners who refuse to have a 13th floor, some superstitious airlines
>   have completely done away with the number “191.”

- Does somebody know some Airlines who are not using this flight number
  for that reason?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can be pretty sure that Delta and American no longer use that flight number, as it is pretty standard for airline to retire a flight number of an accident flight.

Beyond that, I'm sure there are a multitude of carriers still using Flight 191.

For example, Air India 191 is [in-flight](http://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/AIC191) at the time of writing . Air Canada 191 is [scheduled](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/ACA191)